# How can we use LDAP to authenticate SMB share in FreeNAS?

Tags: ldap, server-message-block, truenas, smbfs

SMB service has been enabled, I can share using freeNAS created users to authenticate SMB share. But how can we use LDAP to authenticate SMB shares? Current LDAP configuration in running on different server.